# How to quit leader mode in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Say I input `SPC f`, then I decide not to do anything, is there any way I can quit the "leader" mode? Currently I just type `ESC`, but it does not seem to be the legit way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is `C-g` which, according to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html), is for cancelling a "running or partially typed command". It's not too different from spamming escape, but it seems to save a keystroke in the `SPC f` scenario.

Hope that helps!